# How to design a variable number of nested for-loops?

Tags: c, for-loop, recursion

How to keep adding for-loop `n` times?

For example, if `n = 3` then for-looping 3 times like below:

```
for() 
 {
  for()
   {
    for()
     {
      //keep adding for-loops depending on n
     }
   }
 }
```

I speculate that recursion might work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to have `n` for loops? Can't you just do `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`? It's not really clear what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If I see 3 nested `for` loops I start to worry, adding them dynamically is simply a crazy thing. You can think about it and how easily this will become expensive. Think that if each loop runs 10 times, with 3 you get 1000, and if you add 1 it becomse 10000. It gorws exponentially of course so doing this is simply crazy. And I am completely sure that whatever it is that you want to do, you don't need this so this is a classic [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: BTW, the whole idea is not *decent*. And you should perhaps explain what the **real** problem is so maybe someone can help you.

Comment: O(n^m) is very scary...

Comment: @kurakura88 It's not only scary, it's not practical so no one ever implements that.

Comment: @kaylum because i like to count ternary number, for example for(i[0]=0;i[0]<3; i[0]++) for(i[1]=0;i[1]<3;i[1]++)for(i[2]=0;i[2]<3;i[2]++) printf("%d%d%d\n",i[0],i[1],i[2]);  000, 001, 002, 010 011 012 020 ....

Comment: @iharob hello, i like to count ternary number , and i like to unfix unit of digits  such as ---, ----, -----, ------, ------,... variable... can you have other idea ?

Comment: The code you posted needs 2 for loops only, `for (int x = 0 ; x < 3 ; x++) { for (i[x] = 0 ; i[x] < 3 ; i[x]++) {}}` apparently.

Comment: @iharob no way!, that is 000 001 002 002 012 022 .... i want like this 000 001 002 010 011 012 020.....

Comment: Even O(n^2) algorithm, which arises on using the for loop 2 times is considered as not efficient. If you are using it more than 2/3 times in your approach, then it can be assured that there exists a much efficient algorithm to it.

Comment: This is a very natural question frequently arising in scientific computation. While you can hard-code `n` nested loops for any fixed `n`, you don't want to do this in general to avoid errors arising from amending the code over-and-over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void recursiveForLoops(int n, int limit)
{
    int i;
    if(n == 0)
    {
        //do something
        return;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < limit; ++i)
    {
        recursiveForLoops(n - 1, limit);    
    }
}
```

This will generate `n` nested `for` loops, each one iterating `limit` times. You could accomplish the same output using a regular, single `for` loop with a `for(i = 0; i < k; ++i)` where `k` is `limit`^`n` (`limit` to the `n`'th power).

Comment: Perhaps this does answer the question, but you SHOULD NEVER DO IT.

Comment: @Polikdir can you count ternary number? not recursively?

Comment: @JeungwooPark What do you mean?

Comment: @Polikdir for(i[0]=0; ip[0]<3; i++) for(i[1]=0; i[1]<3; i++) for (i[2]=0;i[2]<3;i++) for(i[3]=0; i[3]<3; i[3]++)   .... keep going....

Comment: @JeungwooPark I'm afraid I still don't understand... You can do it using this function with this call `recursiveForLoops(n, 3);`. If you have another different question you should ask a new one.